# Why can't Thread.interrupt() interrupt a thread trying to acquire lock

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, synchronized

In the book Thinking in Java it is written that `Thread.interrupt()` cannot interrupt a thread which is trying to acquire a synchronized lock, I want to know why?

Comment: It can interrupt the thread. The thread just won't stop waiting for the synchronized lock when it's interrupted, as it would (by throwing an InterruptedException) if it was sleeping, for example. But if the thread obtains the lock, then check if it's interrupted, it will be.

Comment: In a well-designed program, no thread would ever hold a lock for longer than it takes to examine and update a few variables.  There should be no need for an interrupt to "wake up" a pending `synchronized` block.  If you think I'm wrong, and your program really does need that ability, then consider using `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock` instead of using `synchronized`.  The `reentrantLock.tryLock(time, unit)` method _can_ be interrupted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A blocking operation can be interrupted only if it is declared to throw `InterruptedException`. Clearly, a `synchronized` block does not declare it, therefore it is impossible to interrupt a thread while it is waiting to acquire a lock.

Alternatively you can use an explicit lock and call `Lock.lockInterruptibly()`.

Answer (score 1):

The book is wrong, unless it is only referring to the `synchronized` keyword. `Object.wait()` throws `InterruptedException`.

Comment: I read the Chinese version of the book, there are a few mistakes, but I think this place is right. This may be my expression is not clear cause your misunderstanding

Comment: @wanghao, if you want to master concurrency then I would strongly recommend "Java Concurrency in Practice (Brian Goetz)".

Comment: @wanhao `Object.wait()` throws `InterruptedException`. There is nothing there to misunderstand. If the book doesn't agree, it's wrong, by definition. If it's talking about the `synchronized` keyword only, you didn't say so. If you have a *reason* to think the book is right and I have misunderstood something, please provide it.